# Reduce a stream to single object without multiple object creation and explicit mutation

Tags: java, java-stream

I want to create an aggregate object after streaming a collection of incoming object. But what I want is to not create a reference outside the stream and mutate that object "explicitly".

Let's take this scenario. I get a list of students. I want to stream the list and collect only certain elements and form a aggregate object named `MySchool`

```java
public record Student(String name, String section, String schoolName) {
}

List<Student> students =

                List.of(
                        new Student("John", "2", "Holy school"),
                        new Student("Raghav", "8", "California school"),
                        new Student("Prem", "5", "Holy school"),
                        new Student("Peter", "7", "California school"),
                        new Student("Akbar", "9", "Arun school"),
                        new Student("Ashok", "6", "Arun school"),
                        new Student("Arun", "4", "Arun school"),
                        new Student("Ram", "2", "Arun school"),
                        new Student("James", "2", "California school")
                );

public class MySchool {

    private List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();

    private int studentCount = 0;

    public MySchool addStudent(Student student) {
        this.students.add(student);
        return this;
    }

    public List<Student> getStudents () {
        return this.students;
    }

    public void addStudentCount() {
        this.studentCount++;
    }

    public int getStudentCount() {
        return this.studentCount;
    }

    
}
```

**I don't want to do like below, where I mutate an external reference**

```java
public void getMySchoolData(List<Student> allStudents) {

        MySchool mySchool = new MySchool();

        allStudents.stream()
                .filter(student -> student.schoolName().equals("Arun school"))
                .forEach(student -> {
                    mySchool.addStudent(student);
                    mySchool.addStudentCount();
                });


        System.out.println(mySchool);
```

To avoid doing like above, I used `reduce()` method of streams, but I ended up creating lot of `MySchool` objects

```java
public void getMySchoolData1(List<Student> allStudents) {
        Optional<MySchool> mySchool = allStudents.stream()
                .filter(student -> student.schoolName().equals("Arun school"))
                .map(this::addStudentsToSchool)
                .reduce((mySchool1, mySchool2) -> {
                    mySchool1.combineMySchool(mySchool2);
                    return mySchool1;
                });

        var sss = mySchool.get();

        System.out.println(sss);

    }


private MySchool addStudentsToSchool(Student student) {

        var mySchool = new MySchool();
        mySchool.addStudent(student);
        mySchool.addStudentCount();

        return mySchool;
    }

// added this method to MySchool class

public void combineMySchool (MySchool otherSchoolObject) {
        this.studentCount+= otherSchoolObject.getStudentCount();
        this.students.addAll(otherSchoolObject.getStudents());

    }
```

As you can clearly see, I am able to successfully avoid external mutation after using `reduce()`, but I end up creating multiple objects and finally combine them and reduce

Is there anyway where I can avoid multiple object creation, rather just create one object and have streams fill that for me and give back ?

Comment: You want to create multiple schools? Grouped by students? So ... `.groupBy`?

Comment: I want to create just one school object finally

Comment: Just an aside: I think code readability is more important/useful than avoiding that `forEach`.

Comment: I think what you want is a collect, not a reduce.

Comment: Create the filtered list and then do `MySchool.getStudents().addAll(theFilteredList);` What am I missing?

Comment: Not exactly related, but keeping count in instance variable `studentCount` is unnecessary complication. You can always get the count using `this.students.size()`.

Comment: @Chaosfire indeed and even if the OP insists on maintaing the redundant counter, the `addStudent` method should take care to increment the counter, instead of relying on the caller to always perform matching `addStudent` and `addStudentCount` calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by using [`Collectors.teeing()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#teeing(java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.function.BiFunction)) API

```java
MySchool mySchool = allStudents.stream()
                .filter(student -> student.schoolName().equals("Arun school"))
                .collect(
                        Collectors.teeing(
                                Collectors.toList(),
                                Collectors.counting(),
                                mySchool()
                        ));
```

And this is my Merger Bi-Function

```java
private BiFunction<List<Student>, Long, MySchool> mySchool() {

        return (students, count) -> {
            var mySchool = new MySchool();
            mySchool.addAllStudents(students);
            mySchool.addStudentCount(count.intValue());
            return mySchool;
        };
    }
```

Teeing is where I get two inputs and giving a merger function will merge and give back the desired result.

Absolutely excellent !!

Answer (score 2):

**DISCLAIMER**: I'd not use this method in production code. I'd favor readability and maintainability over anything else. Use with caution.

I'd also look at the design of the MySchool class to make it more flexible for example. It can for example accept a `Stream` or a `List` in its constructor.

---

You can use a `Collector` for this. It only creates an intermediary `List`.

```java
public static class MySchoolCollector implements Collector<Student, List<Student>, MySchool> {

    private static final MySchoolCollector INSTANCE = new MySchoolCollector();

    @Override
    public Supplier<List<Student>> supplier() {
        return ArrayList::new;
    }

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<List<Student>, Student> accumulator() {
        return List::add;
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<List<Student>> combiner() {
        return (l1, l2) -> {
            l1.addAll(l2);
            return l1;
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Function<List<Student>, MySchool> finisher() {
        return studentsList -> {
            MySchool mySchool = new MySchool();
            studentsList.forEach(mySchool::addStudent);
            studentsList.forEach(student -> mySchool.addStudentCount());
            return mySchool;
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
        return Set.of(UNORDERED);
    }
}
```

Which you can use like this

```
MySchool school = students.stream()
        .filter(student -> student.schoolName().equals("Arun school"))
        .collect(MySchoolCollector.INSTANCE);

System.out.println(school);
```